# Missing Required Header: for adding content in Microsoft Storage Explorer with C#

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Нi, everybody! Faced with the issue when trying to use local Microsoft Azure Storage for uploading files through **Data Lake Service Client** in c#. 
As connection string to emulator used:
`"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`

Code used:

```
DataLakeServiceClient _dataLakeClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(connectionString)
DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient _dataLakeClient.GetFileSystemClient(containerNameLowercase);
DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient(path);
DataLakeFileClient fileClient = await directoryClient.CreateFileAsync(name);
```

Problem occurs in : `await directoryClient.CreateFileAsync(name)`

Exception occurs:
[image]

Versions:

- StorageEmulator: 5.10
- Azure Storage Explorer: 1.23.3
- Language: C#

If you have any suggestions in how to handle it, feel free in your answers.

**Updated**: Required header is: `x-ms-blob-type`.
So I faced with another problem, how to add that header to DataLakeFileClient header?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You code looks correct, the problem is the missing header file in your request. As mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet#upload-a-file-to-a-directory), to upload a file to a directory first we need create a file reference in the target directory by creating an instance of the **DataLakeFileClient** class. Then upload a file by calling the **DataLakeFileClient.AppendAsync** method. And lastly we need to make sure to complete the upload by calling the **DataLakeFileClient.FlushAsync** method. As shown in the below.

```cs
public async Task UploadFile(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient) 
{ 
    DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("my-directory");
    DataLakeFileClient fileClient = await directoryClient.CreateFileAsync("uploaded-file.txt"); 
    FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\contoso\\Temp\\file-to-upload.txt"); 
    long fileSize = fileStream.Length; 
    await fileClient.AppendAsync(fileStream, offset: 0); 
    await fileClient.FlushAsync(position: fileSize); 
}
```

To solve this problem first we need to find out which Header is missing in the request as the error code says **MissingRequiredHeader**.

Try to use **fiddler** and look at the **http Request and Response** for more clear view and figure it out which header is missing and try adding the required headers [from this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx) (like **x-ms-blob-type** for example).

I would also suggest you to specify explicit service endpoints in your connection string instead of using the default endpoints. For more information check this [Create a connection string for an explicit storage endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string#create-a-connection-string-for-an-explicit-storage-endpoint) section of MS Document.

Comment: Problem occurs when I trying to createFile as in code in your code above also in your **document** they use connection to azure datalake. Used fiddler it doesn't return missing headers. Also used explicit service endpoints. The main problem that I have is where to add properly headers. Tried to fileClient.SetHttpHeaders. Maybe I do it in wrong way but thanks for your response. I will add more description to problem.

Comment: Rechecked fiddler it says x-ms-blob-type is missing. So I should somehow to add it to header. Thanks for help!